# Extjs unpress button

Tags: button, extjs

I have an ExtJS button like this:

```
new Ext.SplitButton({
    text: 'Index',
    iconCls: 'index',
    scale: 'large',
    iconAlign: 'left',
    cls: 'header-item',
    handler: leftPanelNav, // handle a click on the button itself
    menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
        items: [
            // these items will render as dropdown
            // menu items when the arrow is clicked:
            {text: 'Item 1'},
            {text: 'Item 2'}
        ]
    })
})
```

His state will be pressed at a time and I want to know how can I unpress it when I want to from script.

Thank you.

Comment: how does an unpressed split button look like?

Comment: It looks like his initial state.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `toggle()` on the button:

<del>http://www.extjs.com/deploy/ext/docs/output/Ext.SplitButton.html</del> (dead link)

http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/docs/output/Ext.SplitButton.html

> If a state it passed, it
>   becomes the pressed state otherwise
>   the current state is toggled.

Comment: I also found using toggle(state, true) useful. In my case I wanted to toggle the state but not trigger the event action